# Is there a way to put a "niente" into Sibelius?

Tags: dynamics, sibelius

“*Niente*” (“Nothing”, usually written as an *n* or *ø*) is pretty much silence. In the piece I’m writing, I would like for the player to fade in and out of silence, using Niente. However, I can’t type the *ø* and when I type the *n* it doesn't bold like it would with any of the other dynamics (goes from mf to ***mf*** when I stop typing). Is there a way in which I can put a niente into Sibelius and have it work?

Comment: Have you tried looking up the reference manual for Sibelius? https://resources.avid.com/SupportFiles/Sibelius/7/EN/reference.pdf There is a section **Types of hairpin** delegating to Notations > Common > Line for ’dashed, dotted and ”from/to silence“ hairpins‘.

Comment: @Lazy, I’d prefer the Niente, but if that’s the only way, I’ll accept that as an answer